# maximum number of leafs in a tree with degrees at most 3.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T=(V,E)$ be a tree such that $10\leq|V|$ and $1\leq deg(u)\leq 3$ for each $u\in V$. What is a good upper bound for number of leafs in $T$ ? Is is true that $\# leafs\leq |V|-4$ ?

Comment: Each non-leaf is connected to at most two leaves, and each leaf is connected to exactly one node, a non-leaf. So there are at least half as many non-leaves as there are leaves. So $\#leaves \leq \frac{2}{3}|V|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euler's formula gives you $V-E+F=2$, for a tree $F=1$, hence $E=V-1$. We also know that the sum over the degrees of all vertices is equal to $2E$, so $\sum_{u\in V}\deg(u)=2V-2$. Let $L$ denote the number of leaves, then 
$$ L + \sum_{u\in V \setminus L}\deg(u)=2V-2 $$ 
As $\deg(u) \le 3$ we can estimate 
$$ L + 3(V-L) \ge 2V-2 $$ 
which gives $L \le \frac{V+2}{2}$. This bound is best possible and attained whenever all non leaf vertices have degree $3$.

Comment: Very nice. I would, however, suggest skipping the reference to Euler’s formula, which holds for planar graphs only, and while trees are planar, it doesn’t seem obvious to show, while $E=V-1$ for trees is easy enough with induction.

Comment: @Mindlack It's pretty obvious that trees are planar (just add edges one by one; since there is no cycle this never disconnects the plane so you can always put the next one in), but more to the point a proof of Euler's formula typically starts "if $F=1$ then the graph is a tree, and we already know trees have $V-1$ edges", so applying Euler to trees is somewhat circular.